# PhpStorm "Save as" open new file

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

This always catches me out, but it appears to be another PhpStorm only quirk. Normally when you "Save as" a document, it will open the new file. This happens in all Adobe products, all Office products, and every other app I can think of... except PhpStorm.

So many times I've forgotten about this quirk and started working over the old file, thinking it was the new one. It's most frustrating.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Unfortunately no.

`Save as` is basically a shortcut for `Save` and then `Refactor | Copy`.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-332 I guess (based on "duplicate" tickets)

---

General suggestions (Captain Obvious):

- Invoke `Refactor | Copy` on desired file *before* making changes in it (so it will sit deep in your mind that the currently edited file will keep changes)
- Use `Local History` to rollback unwanted changes in old/original file.

Comment: Thanks. JetBrains are can be quite good at spotting things like this when they're posted to SO. Maybe they'll change the behaviour to be more inline with every other app on the planet. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Ask in the ticket to see what they will have to say. Ticket is in "Backlog" project ... so unlikely to be in their current "to implement" list

Comment: Thanks for linking to the ticket. It's 2021 and we're still seeing the same behaviour, so I wonder if it will ever reach the top of the pile!